# self hosted r shiny app wont display all the content

Tags: r, nginx, shiny, leaflet, openvpn

I got troubles with running a selfhosted (arch-server) nginx/shiny app through vpn (openvpn). Parts of it are displayed on other machines, but leaflet/datatable objects are not.

In the local network it works fine. The shiny-webpage itself got a http link, but apparently leaflet (maybe also DT) uses https.

What is completely strange, is that for a colleague using openvpn under win10, it worked.

Could anybody point me to fix this?

OS client: 
Ubuntu 18.04, 
openvpn 2.4.4-2ubuntu1;

OS server: 
Arch Linux
nginx 1.14.0-1

R server: 
R version 3.5.1, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
shiny_1.1.0
leaflet_2.0.1

nginx.conf

```
user html;
worker_processes  1;

events {
worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
include       mime.types;
default_type  application/octet-stream;
sendfile        on;
keepalive_timeout  65;

map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default upgrade;
    '' close;
}

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

location / {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:3838;
     proxy_redirect http://localhost:3838/ $scheme://$host/;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
    proxy_read_timeout 20d;
    proxy_buffering off;
}
```

shiny-server.conf:

```
# Instruct Shiny Server to run applications as the user "shiny"
run_as xyz;

# Define a server that listens on port 3838
server {
  listen 3838;

# Define a location at the base URL
location / {

# Host the directory of Shiny Apps stored in this directory
site_dir /home/xyz/app;

# Log all Shiny output to files in this directory
log_dir /var/log/shiny-server;

# When a user visits the base URL rather than a particular application,
# an index of the applications available in this directory will be shown.
directory_index on;
           }
       }
```

Comment: You will have to provide more details. What's your nginx/proxy configuration? How do you come to the conclusion that leaflet uses HTTPS?

Comment: link: https://github.com/rstudio/leaflet/issues/408; apparently the addtiles function uses https.

Comment: Update: for my colleagues on windows machines it works even through vpn. Seems to be a problem of my openvpn-setup (Ubuntu 18.04). After some time, a "Disconnected from Server" message pops up and the connection freezes.

Comment: If you need help with this issue you will have to provide more details, even though a [mcve] might be difficult.